# Need help doing Scene Transition Better

Tags: position, godot, gdscript

I made a scene transition system, quite fine, but i discovered a bug in it, on a body enter area, i remove the old scene, load the new scene, get the player location in the new scene and then set players location in the new scene, but it appears that for a splitt second, so is the player in the old scene location(x,y,z) in the new scene, before its correctly teleported, which justs happends to be the location for an auto pickup item, which is how i discovered it.

I tried a bit to see if i could disable the node, the player or anything underneath it, but even it all fail, it runs thought the code, executes the code below, no problems, then moves it appearently. So disabling the input is not a solution.

Another issue i suppose is that all scenes contain a dictonary of the spawn location, so they need to be loaded and instanciated just to get the spawn location. Is there a better way to do it? So that it does not trigger the body in area signal on moment before its teleported to where its supposed to be.

```
func transition_to_scene(new_scene:String,goto_point:String=""):

next_scene = new_scene
spawn_point = goto_point


# turn player off to prevent triggering things.
player.stop_inputs()
player.set_process(false)
player.set_process_input(false)
get_tree().paused = true
current_scene_holder.set_block_signals(true)


# Change transition code here.
var localSceneHandler = current_scene_holder.get_child(0)
localSceneHandler.queue_free()
var scene = load(next_scene).instantiate()


var area_Name:String = scene.Area_Display_Name[spawn_point]
area_Name = "  " + area_Name
$"Fade to Black/NinePatchRect/Panel/Label".text = area_Name



# Set Player Location in scene,
var player_spawn_point:Vector3 = scene.get_spawn_point(spawn_point)
player.set_location(player_spawn_point)


# turn player on again.
player.set_process(true)
player.set_process_input(true)
get_tree().paused = false
player.start_inputs()

current_scene_holder.set_block_signals(false)

current_scene_holder.add_child(scene)
```

I need Some way to not trigger Area 3D, and in general just pause or move the node before it updates. Is there anyway to do this? I would like to keep the details of where the doors in the scene are within the scene itself so i don't have to copy paste coordinates over to different scene, and the scenes become self contained.

Edit: Suppose i can mention that i did set it to player.process_mode = Node.PROCESS_MODE_DISABLED in a test, but i suspect the problem is that its location is not updated until next process "round" so i can set as much safety as i want without it affecting it, because it will always be at the old location without change at all times while this script is run, until next "round".

Comment: What about hiding the player during transition and show it in the ready function of the scene?

Comment: Nope, don't work.

Comment: I suppose I could say i found a workaround and had to process be staggered as a fix, not elegant.